# How do I get my browser to render a "success" page after a login POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Res.sendFile works, but my localhost:3000 does not automatically change to localhost:3000/success.html

How do get my browser to show localhost:3000/success.html when i click on Submit?

When I Click submit, it indeed serves up the "success.html" as a response when i check using the chrome dev tools, but my browser does not change the url

```
const express = require('express'). // Include ExpressJS
const app = express(). // Create an ExpressJS app
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Middleware
const path = require("path")

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Route to Homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/static/index.html');
});

// Route to Login Page
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/static/login.html');
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  // Insert Login Code Here
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'success.html'));
});

const port = 3000 // Port we will listen on

// Function to listen on the port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`This app is listening on port ${port}`));**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `express` [redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) `res.redirect('path')` in your case:

```
res.redirect('success.html');
```

Comment: Hi sorry, it still does not work... I added a picture for more clarity. Basically the file is served as a response, but the url does not change